# How do I manually install tasks presented to me in the installer?

Tags: server, package-management

Recently I installed Ubuntu 10.04 LTS server and I messed up and didnt select ssh, dns, lamp and tomcat as things that I wanted to install, it is now done with the install process and how do now manually download and install these?

Answer (score 1):

You can run tasksel manually:

```
sudo tasksel
```

to see the list of packages again after installation.

Comment: how come in this list im not seeing tomcat, dns or lamp?